# How to switch languages with the i18next plugin?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, i18next, language-switching

I am using Backbone.js in my application and the [i18next](http://i18next.com/) plugin for my language switch function on my application. When I pass a value to the `lng` option in the `init` function call, then it translates my page correctly.

Now I want to do this dynamically via a language selector. I have a `<select>`  of four languages and I want to pass the value of the selected language to the `lng` option of the init function.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-6>
    <select class="form-control language-selector">
        <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">Français</option>
        <option value="it">Italiano</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
i18next.init({
        debug: true,
        languages: ['de','en','fr','it'],
        lng: 'de',  
        fallbackLng: false,
        load: 'current',
        resources: resBundle
    }, function(err, t){

});

'change .language-selector': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    i18next.setLng($(e.target).val(), (err, t) => {
        console.log(arguments);
        this.render();
    });
}
```

Comment: have you tried to print your i18n model after changin the language to see if is not a problem with your setLng? if the model is really getting the language changed?

Comment: @rule: I get an error "i18next.setLng" is not a function.

Comment: check if i18next is initialized .. do console in callback function of init.

Comment: @SunilBN: Yes, when I load the application then i18next. init() function is initialized but when I change the language via select then it gives me error i18next.setLng is not a function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function to change the language is [`i18next.changeLanguage`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage). You only need to call it, there's no need to call `init` again or to *"change the init options"* as the options are attributes inside i18next and they are managed through the [API](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api) (the functions).

```
i18next.init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: ['en', 'de', 'fr', 'it'],
});

// catch the event and make changes accordingly
i18next.on('languageChanged', (lng) => {
    // E.g. set the moment locale with the current language
    moment.locale(lng);

    // then re-render your app
    app.render();
});
```

In the view with the language selector:

```
const LangView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'change .language-selector': 'onLangChange',
    },

    onLangChange(e) {
        // only change the language
        i18next.changeLanguage(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
});
```

## Proof of concept

```js
const app = {};

app.translations = {
    "fr": {
        "translation": {
            "label": "Choisir une langue",
            "fr": "Français",
            "en": "Anglais"
        }
    },
    "en": {
        "translation": {
            "label": "Choose a language",
            "fr": "French",
            "en": "English"
        }
    }
};

i18next.init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: ['en', 'fr'],
    resources: app.translations,
});

// catch the event and make changes accordingly
i18next.on('languageChanged', (lng) => {

    // then re-render your app
    app.view.render();
});

const LangView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#selector').html()),
    langTemplate: _.template('<option value="<%= value %>"><%= name %></option>'),
    events: {
        'change .language-selector': 'onLangChange',
    },

    render() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            label: i18next.t('label')
        }));
      
        // cache the jQuery object of the select
        this.$selector = this.$('.language-selector');
      
        // then dynamically populate it
        this.populateSelector();

        return this;
    },

    populateSelector() {
        // for each languages in i18next, add an option to the select
        _.each(i18next.languages, this.addLanguage, this);
    },

    addLanguage(lang) {
        // adding the option with the translated names
        this.$selector.append(this.langTemplate({
            value: lang,
            name: i18next.t(lang),
        }));
    },

    onLangChange(e) {
        // change the language
        i18next.changeLanguage(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
});

app.view = new LangView();

$('#app').html(app.view.render().el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next/4.1.1/i18next.min.js"></script>

    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/template" id="selector">
        <label>
            <%=label %>
          </label>
        <select class="form-control language-selector"></select>
    </script>
```

Regarding translating the language names, take a look at [Language of language names in the language selector?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/37017/100147)

Comment: @harsh yes, I corrected that. I have a service module named `i18n` in my app which is i18next in the background and forgot to change the name back.

Comment: I dont use moment.locale in my view. What is the alternative of that.?

Comment: @harsh that is just an example of stuff to handle there, you can completely ignore moment.

Comment: Ok, but still I get an error."cannot read property 'render' of undefined" I defined .on method after the .init method, and both are in initialize function. I am confused that why this.render(); is not working in my i18next.on method.

Comment: Of-course I understand what I am doing..;) and I already found out what the problem was. I am calling another API in initialization and it needs also the lang parameter. That's why it wasn't working. I need to figure out that. But as per this question your solution is working good. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    i18n.init({
        "lng": 'en',
        "resStore": resources,
        "fallbackLng" : 'en'
    }, function (t) {
        $(document).i18n();
    });

   'change .language-selector': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        i18n.init({
        lng: $(e.target).val()}, (err, t) => {
            console.log(arguments);
            $(document).i18n();
        });
   }
}
```

I dunno backbone.js. [Working solution in normal JavaScript is here](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/dLc7x/)

Comment: unfortunately this solution is not working for me. I think, I need to just pass the value of "lng" when it gets changed. But I don't know how can I do this? And also update the init options when "lng" get changed.